# How to insert a psd file into a separate LAYER of an already OPEN psd file APPLESCRIPT

Tags: file, applescript, alias, photoshop, layer

I am trying to write a code that automizes a creation of a file. I need to insert another psd file as a separate layer into the one that the program is creating. I also need to adjust the size and position of the inserted file. The inserted file is psd. I am currently working in photoshop-cc15. I am working in AppleScript and need the solution in AppleScript as well. I am also working in Photoshop CC15

I have tried load and open commands, but for some reason photoshop does not see the file. I have checked the path of the file multiple times and it is definitely correct.

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2015"
    -- Create a new document.
    set docRef to make new document with properties ¬
        {width:5 as inches, height:6 as inches, resolution:300}

    tell docRef
        -- Unlock the background layer and fill it with gray color
        set background layer of layer 1 of docRef to false
        fill selection with contents {class:RGB color, red:200, green:200, blue:200}

        -- Insert the first diamond into the file
        set myPath to alias ¬ 
            "Macintosh HD⁩/Users/⁨tikhonpachin/⁨Documents⁩/⁨Work⁩/⁨VK⁩/⁨Word of the Day/Diamond.psd"
        load myPath
    end tell
end tell
```

The expected result is a diamond inserted into my canvas as a separate layer. The diamond is the file that I want to insert. I also need to know how to adjust its properties, such as height, width and position on the canvas related to other layers. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that you're specifying the path incorrectly. Photoshop wants a POSIX path, and local POSIX paths never show the disk name. Further, you don't want/need to use the 'alias' keyword, which creates a different kind of path specifier. You should code the path like so:

```
set myPath to "⁩/Users/⁨tikhonpachin/⁨Documents⁩/⁨Work⁩/⁨VK⁩/⁨Word of the Day/Diamond.psd"
```

I have an ancient version of Photoshop (CS4) so terminology may have changed and features you have may not be available on my end. That being said, I don't see a way to load an image directly into a layer on another image. You'll probably have to create a new layer in your docRef document, open the diamond image in a separate window, then copy/paste or move the image across into the new layer. If you look at the Photoshop Scripting dictionary in Script Editor, you'll see that most of the image manipulation routines have the same names as they have in the the menus and panels: `Resize image`, `rotate`, `scale`, `translate`... It shouldn't be too difficult to figure out which you need to use.

If you have any more specific question, please feel free to ask, but toss-all questions like "I also need to know how to..." don't work well. It's like getting in the driver's seat, starting down the road, and then saying "Oh, can you also tell me how to avoid hitting other cars?" There's really no good answer to give to that kind of thing.